# json files downloaded by aws s3 sync / aws s3 cp are incomplete

Tags: json, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I downloaded .json file from amazon s3, but its content is just a value of the first key/value pair.

original json file is like this:

```
{
    "_1": [
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "Type": "type"
        }
    ]
}
```

but downloaded json file is not even json file, it only has list inside.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "name",
    "Type": "type"
  }
]
```

I tried aws s3 sync / aws s3 copy / aws s3api get-object and all of its result is same.

I only want to download original file from the s3 bucket.

is there any solution?

- Updates

I just copied the original content on the s3 select from preview and saved it as a file.

I found out its md5 checksum and file size is totally different with the object overview.

It seems the original file on the s3 bucket is corrupted, but I'm not sure how its preview is still same as the original content.

Comment: It is highly likely that you are correctly viewing the contents of the file that was stored on S3. It might have been incorrectly uploaded. How was it uploaded or placed into S3? Do you still have the original file? How many bytes does it contain? Does that match the length of the object in S3?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for reply! No, I checked md5sum and file size and both original and downloaded file are same.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Maybe the original file is already corrupted, because its file size can't be same if the file is different.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein But if it is, I don't know why the "select from" of the s3 object shows its original content.

Comment: Ah! You did not mention that you were using Amazon S3 SELECT. The output from S3 Select will be different to simply viewing the raw file. It is selecting rows and returning data in a different format. That is correct behaviour.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Oh, I didn't know that. Is it different even if I select JSON format on the S3 SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

I found out `aws s3api select-object-content` can give me same result as the S3 select from preview but without indents.

For indents, I decided to reindent after I receive the uncorrupted results.

I used below command to retrieve my json files.

```
aws s3api select-object-content \
  --bucket $BUCKET \
  --key $KEY --expression "select * from s3object" \
  --expression-type 'SQL' \
  --input-serialization '{"JSON": {"Type": "LINES"}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}' \
  --output-serialization '{"JSON": {}}' \
  /dev/stdout | python -mjson.tool > $KEY
```